# Particle age acting weird (particle info node)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

[image: Particle Node]

The colors are equally distributed in the color ramp node but, for some reason, the really bright parts are only shown in the first two frames of the particle age, as seen in the picture.

Even when I remove the color ramp and connect it straight to the emission, it comes out with the same result but in black and white.

How do I fix this?